# FullCalendar - all the months on 1 page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I can't find a way to show all the months from Jan to Dec on a page using **FullCalendar plugin**. I wanted to look something like this: 
[image]

For each month I want to resize it to approx 250px

I tried this code and it doesn't resize the `width to 250px`:

```
$('#calendarJan').fullCalendar({
          editable: false,
          events: 'ajax-calender.php?month=jan',
          height: 50,
          eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
                     $(element).css('width','250px');
               }
});
```

HTML

```
  <div style='background-color:white; padding:5px;'>
   <div id='calendarJan'></div>
   <div id='calendarFeb'></div>
   <div id='calendarMar'></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the width of the div you're placing it in.. something like this:

```
document.getElementById('calendarJan').setAttribute("style", "width: 250px");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                    height: 650,
                    themeSystem: 'Sandstone',
                    headerToolbar: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'multiMonthYear,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,dayGridDay,list'
                    },
```

For the new Updated version of Fullcalendar@6.1.10

`right: 'multiMonthYear,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,dayGridDay,list'`

This 'multiMonthYear' answers your question

Answer (score 0):

This is now built-in with "Multi-Month View"

docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/multimonth-grid

demo: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/multimonth-grid-demo